# How can I add another Directory Admin on OpenDirectory

Tags: user-account, open-directory, serveradmin

Right now, I am planning to have another account on my OpenDirectory on our Mac Server. How can I add another Directory Admin on OpenDirectory?

I already added a user but I thinks it's not it. I already read some articles about adding users but I can't find one about Adding Another Directory Admin on OpenDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a second Directory Admin by either using the Server.app GUI or via command line to your OD server.

GUI:

- Open Server.app and enable View > Show System Accounts
- In the sidebar choose Accounts > Users
- Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button at the bottom to add a new user:

  [image]

  Choose *Local Network Directory* for Directory, enter all details and save the user.
- Right-click the new user > Advanced Options... and add or modify further details:

  [image]
- Right-click the new user > Edit User... and remove all group memberships except Administrators, Open Directory Users and Open Directory Administrators

  [image]

More or less without GUI:

- Use a predefined/precreated ldif file and import it:

  ```
  0x0A 0x5C 0x3A 0x2C dsRecTypeStandard:Users 11 dsAttrTypeStandard:Expire dsAttrTypeStandard:Change dsAttrTypeStandard:FirstName dsAttrTypeStandard:UserShell dsAttrTypeStandard:GeneratedUID dsAttrTypeStandard:PrimaryGroupID dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID dsAttrTypeStandard:LastName dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName dsAttrTypeStandard:NFSHomeDirectory
  0:0:Directory:/bin/tcsh:24DCA574-8E9D-4F1A-84B5-79A18882F5CF:20:diradmin3:1002:Administrator3:Directory Administrator3:/private/var/root
  ```

  The UUID (*24DCA574-8E9D...*) has been generated with `uuidgen`. Also change UID, all names and other details.
- Import the file with:

  ```
  dsimport /Users/user/Desktop/file.ldif /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 O -u diradmin -p <diradmin_password>
  ```
- add/modify password and group memberships of the new *diradmin3* with tools like `dscl` or the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, will try this first before I mark your answer as correct! Thanks!